# Pushing messages to be spoken to Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

How do I force Alexa to speak messages? For example everytime someone mentions Elon Musk on Twitter I want my Alexa to automatically speak the tweet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. SO is for asking questions about: a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tool commonly used by programmers. It should be a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Your question may be better suited to another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet to trigger Alexa directly without Alexa wasn't asked. You could use notifications. Alexa will have a yellow ring and user has to ask for messages.

See https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html fro details.